# Can an algorithm safely resolve to self assignment of input to output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, variable-assignment

I am developing an application where I define multiple algorithms to work on an array of data, with the generic form:

Apply [algorithm[k]] to data at [i] and save at [o]

Narrowing to my doubt:

a) It's possible that the input and output are the same object, like when applying Gaussian filter to an image.

b) It's possible that the algorithm resolve to an no-op, like when interpolating an array of data to other of the same size.

When (a) and (b) happens at the same time, the following part of the algorithm

```
o[output_position]=process(i[input_position]);
```

Will resolute to

```
o[output_position]=o[output_position];
```

Is this safe?

---

Some quite-not-polished reasoning:

I assume it is, mostly because (but i don't feel confident with this assumption) memory-to-memory moves resolves to memory-to-register-to-memory move.

It worked with some simple tests, but I don't have the knowledge to say to someone "look at my well-designed code".

I plan to compile with optimization flags and move on to other portions of the project, so I worry that somewhere in the future things go BOOM and there goes another nice day spent on the debugger to trace this self-assignment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends entirely on the type of `o[output_position]`. If it implements the assignment operator correctly, then it's fine. A correctly implemented assignment operator always works fine with self-assignment.

The idiomatic implementation of the assignment operator in C++ uses the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap). This then implies correct self-assignment, even without the `this != &other` check you'll often see in other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

While using basic types (int, float, char), your reasoning will be fine - any assignment is done by memory-register-memory which is fast enough.

When using objects you will need to correctly implement the assignment operator (operator=). This will most likely be done by checking, as you must, that you're not assigning an object to itself:

```
Object operator=(const Object& other) {
    if (&other == this) { return *this };

    // your assignment code here!
}
```

Comment: Not true, or at least not a complete answer. First of all, if your class only uses member variables which themselves have correct assignment semantics, then it's redundant (and even error-prone) to implement your own assignment operator. Second, if you use copy-and-swap, you don't need the self-assignment check except perhaps for some exotic optimization cases.

Comment: Tanks, @Arie, I forgot to mention I'm actually worried about basic types, because then the assignment happens locally (by that I mean no copy operator called)

Comment: @Kahler: copy and assignment are related, but not the same :) Anyway, assigning basic types is always fine. You can run into problems with pointers, but that depends on the desired ownership semantics (assigning an address versus assigning what's pointed to). So, all things considered, I think your question is good and well expressed, but perhaps should have mentioned a few more implementation details.